# Move up, right, left and down functions

Tags: javascript

I have some code which moves the users position up, right, down or left depending on the direction entered.

```
function up(field, player) {
    player.column = player.column + 1;
    field[player.row][player.column] = 'P'; 
}

function right(field, player) {
    player.row = player.row + 1;
    field[player.row][player.column] = 'P';
}

function down(field, player) {
    player.column = player.column - 1;
    field[player.row][player.column] = 'P';
}

function left(field, player) {
    player.row = player.row - 1;
    field[player.row][player.column] = 'P';
}
```

The code works fine for what I need, but I was curious if there is a more efficient way of writing the 4 functions above? As in maybe use one function rather than 4?

*note*
Edge cases will be implemented - if the next position is greater than the dimensions of the field, etc. So I'm not sure if this will impact making it more efficient

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about

```
function move(field, player, dx, dy) {
    player.column = player.column + dx;
    player.row = player.row + dy;
    field[player.row][player.column] = 'P'; 
}
```

and instead of calling `up(field, player)`, call `move(field, player, 0, -1)`? With your input, that would basically be

```
switch(input) {
case 'up':
    move(field, player, 0, -1);
    break;
case 'right':
    move(field, player, 1, 0);
    break;
case 'left':
    move(field, player, -1, 0);
    break;
case 'down':
    move(field, player, 0, 1);
    break;
}
```

I assume you'll have more code, like checking if the move is valid, resetting the `field` at the current player position, etc., which won't be duplicated this way. A more complete example might be

```
function move(field, player, dx, dy) {
    // Valid move?
    let newColumn = player.column + dx;
    let newRow = player.row + dy;
    if (newColumn < 0 || newColumn >= WIDTH ||
        newRow < 0 || newRow >= HEIGHT)
        return;
    // Player cannot hit wall
    if (field[newRow][newColumn] == 'X')
        return;

    // Make move
    field[player.row][player.column] = ' ';
    player.column = newColumn;
    player.row = newRow;
    field[player.row][player.column] = 'P'; 
}
```

> Edge cases will be implemented - if the next position is greater than the dimensions of the field, etc. So I'm not sure if this will impact making it more efficient

It might seem unnecessary to verify `newColumn` when you're making a move in the y (row) direction, but comparisons like that are extremely cheap and you shouldn't be worried about their performance.

Comment: I like this a lot... But I'm not sure if it would work with the input. The input is an array of strings like `up, right, right, down, east, east, west`. So if west, - 1 on the the rows, +1 for east, etc. I may be not understanding your code, but I'm not sure how this function can interperate when to add + 1 for going up, -1 for going down, etc. Thanks though

Comment: See my updated answer for an example how to act on different input strings.

Comment: Thank you, it makes more sense now. Never considered using switch statements.

Answer (score 4):

Your functions are called up, east, down, up. That's a strange combination of directions.

Either name them north, east, south, west. Or up, left, down, right.

Instead of saying `variable = variable + 1`, you can also say `variable += 1`, which is shorter and more to the point.

And for `variable += 1` there is another abbreviation, which is `variable++`.

Comment: You're right. I'm not sure why I named them like that - in my production code it's like how you wrote it. Thanks for the heads up

Comment: Possible invalidation of this answer?